Unable to Parse time in format hhmmss to LocalTime in Java
I am trying parse '093000' as follows in java:
LocalTime parsed = LocalTime.parse("093000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhmmss"));

However I am running into this exception and can't seem to figure it out
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '093000' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=30, HourOfAmPm=9, SecondOfMinute=0, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2023)

Is it something to do with AM/PM ?

either use HH, or drop the DateTimeFormatter: LocalTime.parse("09:30:00"); with ':' between the parts

Please try HHmmss instead of hhmmss. The hh describes the clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12) and HH is for hour-of-day (0-23).
LocalTime parsed = LocalTime.parse("093000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));


h is the pattern character for the "hour of am/pm" field, not the "hour of day" field, which is likely what you intended.
Since 09 is interpreted as the "hour of am/pm" field, it is ambiguous whether this is 9am or 9pm, so the parsing fails. If you want 09 to mean 9am, and 21 to mean 9pm, you should use the H pattern character.
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss")

See also the list of pattern characters in the documentation.

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Time {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime parsedTime = LocalTime.parse("093000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));

        String formattedOutput = parsedTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));
        System.out.println(parsedTime); // 09:30
        System.out.println(formattedOutput);  // 093000
    }
}

I think the above code should solve your problem. 'hhmmss' formats strings in a 12 hour format, while' HHmmss' formats strings in a 24 hour format. Therefore, it's worth changing the format.

Thanks for demonstrating with full yet minimal working code. I would extract DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss") into a constant (in production code I would consider it a requirement, but it’s a matter of how far you want to develop a Stack Overflow answer).
